# Allow Number object to be null in Tapestry BeanEditor

Tags: java, abstract-class, tapestry

I have an object I'd like to edit via beaneditor. One of the properties is of the `Number` class.

When I try to display the beaneditor, I get the following error:

> Parameter 'translate' of component core/PropertyEditBlocks:numberfield
>   is bound to null. This parameter is not allowed to be null.

When I changed the variable type to `Double`, everything worked fine.

Does it have anything to do with the fact that `Number` is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated? In that case, should I provide some sort of a translator or something like that so it uses, `Double` for example, when editing the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TextField](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/TextField.html)'s require a `translate` parameter. Tapestry has defaults registered for String, Integer, Long etc. Since tapestry can't find a `org.apache.tapestry5.FieldTranslator` it's complaining.

Solutions:

1. Use a concrete type instead of Number
2. Explicitly pass a FieldTranslator to the TextField (eg set the `translate` parameter)
3. Register a `FieldTranslator` for Number (this sounds crazy to me).

Comment: Thanks :)

Since I'm in need of using `Number` class, I'm gonna go with #2 (or #3 just for some practice) :)

Comment: #3 does not make sense conceptually

Comment: Could you, please, give me an example when it would make the most sense out to use #3?

Comment: It doesn't make sense... ever. Number is an abstract concept whereas FieldTranslator is a concrete concept.

Comment: I mean in general :) But I'll remember this as well :)